# Is it possible to use an Attribute implementing a Fody weaver outside the project it is implemented?

Tags: c#, aop, fody

I can't intercept method join points when using an Attribute implementing a Fody weaver on methods outside the project the Attribute has been implemented in.

I have implemented a MethodDecorator.Fody weaver in a project but when I try to add the Attribute to any method outside the project, weaving does not occur. It works in the same project though.

```
[AttributeUsage(AttributeTargets.Method)]
public class RelayExceptionsAttribute : Attribute, IMethodDecorator
{
    public void Init(object instance, MethodBase method, object[] args)
    { }
    public void OnException(Exception exception)
    {
        Console.WriteLine(exception.Message);
    }
    public void OnEntry() { }

    public void OnExit() { }
}
```

When I use this Attribute on a method in the same project, OnException (and other methods in the Attribute) are hit as expected. When I put it on methods outside the project (but have the project the Attribute is defined as a reference) no interception occurs.

Comment: Did you double check that Fody itself is actually active for that new project?

Comment: Yes I added both Fody and MethodDecorator.Fody as NuGet packages to the new project. I also copied the same FodyWeavers.xml and .xsd from the project the Attribute is implemented.

Answer (score 1):

Apply module to the  MethodDecorator.Fody implementation

```
[module: RelayExceptions]
[AttributeUsage(AttributeTargets.Method)]
    public class RelayExceptionsAttribute : Attribute, IMethodDecorator
    {
        public void Init(object instance, MethodBase method, object[] args)
        { }
        public void OnException(Exception exception)
        {
            Console.WriteLine(exception.Message);
        }
        public void OnEntry() { }

        public void OnExit() { }
    }
```

In another project that has reference mention [module: RelayExceptions]

```
[module: RelayExceptions]

class Test{
[RelayExceptions]
public void AnyMethod()
{
//some code
}
}
```

Comment: What is the reason for using the module: keyword / attribute?